# Floatstyle how to come back to the default theme

Tags: floats, boxes

How can I come back to the default `floatstyle` after I called the `floatstyle{boxed}` and the `\restylefloat{figure}` command?

Comment: Hi Nathan, welcome to tex exchange! I edited your code using ticks so that the latex snippets are rendered. I also removed the thanks- this may seem strange, but it helps to keep the site in a Q&A format

Answer (score 5):

You can return to `plain` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A
  \caption{A boxed figure}
\end{figure}

\floatstyle{plain}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A
  \caption{A regular figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]